# Finding a link Element in Selenium which contains a specific word in its href with python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation, chrome-web-driver

I am **windows 7** user using **python 3.6.7** and **chromedriver 83.3**
I love automating stuff with python and recently started **web automation with selenium and chromedriver**. So i am pretty new to this field.

I wrote a script that can download any software from the internet after, (spending hours on tutorials and documentation reading) upon giving it a search query. Here is my script:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests, bs4

query = input("Name for a windows software: ")
searchGoogle = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+"download "+str(query)+" for windows 7"

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

links = []
website = requests.get(searchGoogle)
website_text = website.text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(website_text,"lxml")
all_links = []
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    links.append(link.get("href"))
for link in links:
    if "/url?q=" in link:
        final = link.replace("/url?q=","")
        final = final.split("&", 1)[0]
        all_links.append(final)

for ss in all_links:
    try:
        driver.get(ss)
        time.sleep(30)
        download = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Download')
        download.click()
        print(download.text)
        quit()
    except:
        #print(download.href)
        print("Not Found... Moving to next...")
        continue
```

the problem is that sometimes it clicks on some links that say "Download" and go to another page which asks "Start Download".

I know that when you download an exe file the link to download contains something like this: "https://something.com/something/**something.exe**"

So i wanted to ask if there was a **find_element_if_its_href_contains('.exe')**
Or: anything that clicks only a link which contains ".exe" in it.

I am new to this community and I am sorry if you find anything in my question that does not meet StackOverflow Expectations. Ask me in the comments and i would be glad to change my question in the way that you suggest.

By The Way, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an xpath or css expression to match webelements with `href` containing the string ".exe":

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@href,'.exe')]")
#or
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[href*='.exe']")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use selenium ver.3.141.0 and I also got another way to fix this problem. 
I just wanted to give some 'partial' string and get the 'whole' link text. The code is below:

```
all_links_by_keyword = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text(your_variables + 'any_string_you_need')
```

For instance, if you want to find links with 'computer' but the page has lots of links including 'computer', like 'computerV01', 'computerV02'...etc. 
Then you can use this to find all links with 'computer' keyword. 
Example code:

```
getComputer = 'computer'
links = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text(getComputer + 'V')
for link in links:
  print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Hope it can help you.